# $http.post from angular reaches php, but response is not received back in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm having this weird issue where you already did something thousands of time but this time won't work. I've been on it for two days and can't fix it.

So my code is very simple :

js :

```
$http.post('datas/test.php', data)
    .success(function(response) 
             console.log(response);
     })
    .error(function() {
             console.log("error");
     });
```

test.php :

```
<?php
$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

When I do a console.log(data) before the $http.post it's containing an object with two fields which are both strings but the console.log(response) give me a null so every time I try to access a variable like $user->something it gives me an error.

I'm having a second issue that is really weird too : when I run my app and call the $http.post it gives me all the errors I said before, but if I try an other time, the $http.post won't call at all until I reboot the server (it's giving me a bad gateway).

I tested many things like changing the way I call my file :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'datas/test.php',
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} // Or 'application/json'
});
```

but this is giving me exactly the same behavior.

Thank you in advance for helping me out and have a good day ! ;)

PS: I'm using PHPStorm in case it has anything to do with the server reboot thing.

Comment: url should be either full url with domain or starting with / and full path.. 
else the request can go in some inner folder..

Comment: @Svetlio the php file is called, it's not a problem from the URL I tested to do things in the PHP file in case it wasn't call but it is. So changing the URL won't change anything, or will it ?

Comment: Then why do you use php://input instead of the globals $_POST ?

Comment: @Sveltio Because by default $http.post is running as application/json from what I know you can't get the data from it with the $_POST

Comment: Better try with post.. HTTP requests are HTTP requests no matter what headers will be set.

Comment: @Svetlio I tried, $_POST is giving me null aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had here came from a FileReader I opened earlier in my JS :

```
reader.readAsBinaryString($scope.file);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
       //stuff
    };
```

the readAsBinaryString function made the file_get_contents("php://input") unable to work correctly.

Once replaced with

```
    reader.readAsDataURL($scope.file);
```

every thing worked fine.

Thanks to Giulio for helping me to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' you should pass the data in the urlencoded format (ie. "var1=val1&var2=val2").

Otherwise, if you use 'application/json', you can pass directly your javascript object.

Let me know if I can help you better.

Bye

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing here the code is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  for a test purpose but i'm using 'application/json' with a javascript object. But this is not working out. My object is null once in my php file

Comment: could you please let me see the result of a `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Array
(
) 
is what I got from print_r($_REQUEST).

Comment: perfect, so can you make a `console.log('data')` on your javascript before the $http.post and let me see the content of your data? You can find the console window inside your browser's development tools.

Comment: As I said in my post, when I do a console.log(data) before the $http.post I have an objects which contains two strings, I can't post the result because one of the strings is very very long.

Comment: so you see something like `{f1: 'v1', f2: 'verylongv2'}`?

Comment: yes more like object : {f1: 'v1', f2: 'verylongv2'}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95545/discussion-between-giulio-molinari-and-vincent-guirou).

Answer (score 1):

**For First Approach**

To use angular $http.post in correct way you shoud handal promise correctly by using .then method not the success method.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Please check the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for using $http.post

**For Second Approach**

Look like data is not transform correctly. By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content-type, "application/json". But you want to post the value as a FORM post, so you need to change the serialization algorithm and post the data with the content-type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Following code reference from [this link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm)

```
var request = $http({
method: "post",
url: "datas/test.php",
transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
data: {
  id: 4,
  name: "Test",
  status: "Something"
}
});

// Store the data-dump of the FORM scope.
request.success(
function( html ) {

$scope.cfdump = html;

}
);
```

And the TransformRequestAsFormPost implementation

```
app.factory(
"transformRequestAsFormPost",
function() {

// I prepare the request data for the form post.
function transformRequest( data, getHeaders ) {

var headers = getHeaders();

headers[ "Content-type" ] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

return( serializeData( data ) );

}


// Return the factory value.
return( transformRequest );


// ---
// PRVIATE METHODS.
// ---


// I serialize the given Object into a key-value pair string. This
// method expects an object and will default to the toString() method.
// --
// NOTE: This is an atered version of the jQuery.param() method which
// will serialize a data collection for Form posting.
// --
// https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L45
function serializeData( data ) {

// If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
if ( ! angular.isObject( data ) ) {

return( ( data == null ) ? "" : data.toString() );

}

var buffer = [];

// Serialize each key in the object.
for ( var name in data ) {

if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {

continue;

}

var value = data[ name ];

buffer.push(
encodeURIComponent( name ) +
"=" +
encodeURIComponent( ( value == null ) ? "" : value )
);

}

// Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
var source = buffer
.join( "&" )
.replace( /%20/g, "+" )
;

return( source );

}

}
);
```

Comment: I'm going to test that. But isn't my first code exemple with suppose to work ? By default it's application/json, fine, i'm sending a javascript object and i'm using $user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) to get it. Do you know where this issue comes from ?

Comment: As per latest angular documentation the correct way to use $http.post is $http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: Alright so I missed something from the latest update. But it's really weird though : i'm doing this everywhere in my app and it's working everywhere but here where I have exactly the same code. I'm gonna test that ASAP and tell you how it is. Keep in touch

Comment: Alright, this fix the "only one time" bug where after testing my app, the $http.post won't call at all. But the object is still null.

Comment: can you check in developer tool if http request trigger from browser, if yes, what is the http response status that you getting from server

Comment: I'm getting a 200 status